# Get-CsOnlineUser equivalent in MS Graph REST API?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to use the MS Graph REST API to look up a Microsoft Teams user, similar to the `get-csOnlineUser` powershell cmdlet.

Specifically, I want to fetch these fields:

```
lineUri
onlineVoiceRoutingPolicy
onlineDialOutPolicy
```

I can look up general user information with the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@company.com` url, but the information returned does not include the above fields.

I tried adding `?$select=lineUri,onlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,onlineDialOutPolicy` to the end of the url to request those fields specifically, but it did not help.

Comment: Please follow below doc which explains how to retrieve the properties and relationships of user object.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=python

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I tried adding `?$select=accountEnabled,userPrincipalName,lineUri,onlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,onlineDialOutPolicy` to the end of the url above, but it only returned values for `accountEnabled` and `userPrincipalName`.  How would I fetch the values for `lineUri`, `onlineVoiceRoutingPolicy`, and `onlineDialOutPolicy`?

Comment: The values for `lineUri`, `onlineVoiceRoutingPolicy`, and `onlineDialOutPolicy` will not be returned by calling this Graph API.

Comment: John Gordeon: Were you able to figure this out? I have similar requirements.

Comment: @TechTurtle No, I was not able to fetch these fields using MS Graph.